# What does "refer you to a letter" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

The following is an example sentence from [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/refer?q=refer):

> May I refer you to my letter of 14 May?

I thought the above sentence might mean one of the followings:

1. Could you bring my letter to me?
2. Could you read my letter?
3. May I write down about you in my letter?

Which does the sentence mean, or does it mean other than the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[refer to](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/refer-to-sth)

> to look at a book or similar record in order to find information and help:

Basically, it means, "Go look at this letter I sent you."  (Only, more tactful.)

Comment: I just upvoted your answer. I **guess** "refer you to" is more tactful than saying "Did you even bother to read my letter dated 14 May?" I prefer to be more explicit while still being polite, "I am sorry that I was not clearer in my letter dated 14 May.  As I said there, ..."

Comment: "Refer to" means that the recipient should go read (or reread) the letter.  Consequently, I would expect the writer to not repeat what was said in it.

Comment: @JeffMorrow -I find that a grovelling apology from me (I do apologise for not having been clearer in my email of xxx) acts as a fairly stinging rebuke to an astute recipient, and if they aren't astute, well....

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I fear most of the recipients of my correspondence who required clarification tended not be astute. I literally had one interpret "may not" as "shall."

Comment: @JeffMorrow Then you would be ill-advised to refer them to a prior letter.

Comment: @Mary In that specific case, I referred them to my lawyer as well.